# Broken Customizer After Migration To The Skeleton Architecture

Tags: theme-customizer, migration

I've been trying to migrate an existing website from the standard Wordpress architecture to the [Skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton/). The plugin stack includes Woocommerce. The theme is i-Craft.

After the installation everything from the composer it starts well, but most of the theme's staff doesn't load, for example, stylesheets, changed via Admin, many features that are set for the theme, and when Customizer is running (which an important dependency for the theme) it reloads its frame because of "Non-existent changeset UUID" for the site's media. As a result, I can't edit the theme at and continue migration.

Help me to investigate the problem, please.

Comment: What is "skeleton architecture"? The first Google result for "skeleton architecture wordpress" is this thread.

Comment: @JacobPeattie the link is https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton/

Comment: @JacobPeattie do you have own thoughts?